# how to get the date for promotion from mysql using php / dynamic price

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php error_reporting(0); ?>
<?php
    session_start;
    include("includes1/db.php");
    include("includes1/functions1.php");
    $_SESSION ["cart"]++;
    if($_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['productid']>0){
        $pid=$_REQUEST['productid']; echo"$pid";
        addtocart($pid,1);
        header("location:product_summary1.php");
        exit();
    }

?>
<html>
<body>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Demo is not available, please try again later");
mysql_select_db("agriculture") or die("Demo is not available, please try again later");

if ( !empty($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] == 'PriceAsc' ) {
    $orderby=" ORDER BY price ASC";
} 
if ( !empty($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] == 'PriceDesc' ) {
    $orderby=" ORDER BY price DESC";
}
?>
<div class="row-fluid"></div>
<ul class="thumbnails">
<?php
$datestart = '15-12-2016';
$dateend = '16-12-2016';
$product_name= 'product_name';
$discount= 'discount';
$price = 'price';
$data=mysql_query("select * from promotion  ".$orderby) or die("select * from promotion"."<br/><br/>
".mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($data)){
?>

<li class="span3">
<div class="thumbnail">

<a  href="product_details.html"><img src="themes/images/products/<?php echo $row['productimage']?>" alt=""/></a>
<div class="caption">
<h5><?php echo $row['name']?></h5>
<h5>PROMOTION END : <?php echo $row['dateend']?></h5>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<h4 style="text-align:center"></i></a> <a class="btn" type="button" value="Add to Cart" onClick="addtocart(<?php echo $row['serial']?>)">Add to <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a> 
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">RM <?php $date = date ('d-m-y');
    if ($date <= $datestart)
    {echo  $total = $row['price'] - $row['discount']."</br>" ;}
    else if ($date <= $dateend)
    {echo $row['price'] ."<br/>";}
    else
    {echo $row['price']."<br/>";
    }?></a> /unit</h4>

</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>

</li>
</ul>


</form></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my promotion page code. i must to use the date that i fill in database. when promotion date expired, the price must changed into price before promotion. so i create the function that i declare the date promotion and use it. but when the promotion date is finish, the price display is changed. but when i click the add to cart, the price is take the promotion price. not standard price. help help me.

Comment: Use mysqli. All the function of mysql_.. has been depreciated.

Comment: i dont know how to use mysqli. tmrw my presentation day. and i dont have any much time to study about it. can u help me please :( :(

Answer (score 0):

try change `date ('d-m-y')` to `date ('d-m-Y')`

Comment: try `echo $date` and change

Comment: change `$datestart = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('15-12-2016'));
$dateend = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('16-12-2016'));`